# Why i cant initialise a variabel with msg.sender

Tags: payable

why i can't initialise a variable

`address payable public owner=msg.sender;`

but i have to do this instead

```
address payable public owner;
constructor() payable 
{
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
}
```

Comment: Because `msg.sender` is not constant, and it will have a value during the contract deployment.